# Append a random string to a post permalink

Tags: posts, customization, permalinks

I'd like take the generated post permalink and append a random string to the end of it.  For instance, if I had: `mywebsite.com/post1`, I'd like for it to be `mywebsite.com/post1-kj4ds` or any other random string.

I've tried using the `wp_unique_post_slug` filter and appending a random string to the resulting slug, but every time I hit 'Publish', the random string gets appended again.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
So here is what I was trying to do:

```
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\new_unique_post_slug', 0, 6);
function new_unique_post_slug($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug) {
    $slug = $slug . 'a random generated slug';
    return $slug;
}
```

I'm not too familiar with Wordpress and filters, but from what I have gathered, this chunk of code runs after the 'wp_unique_post_slug' runs? Is there a way to append a random string to the permalink, and THEN run 'wp_unique_post_slug'?

Comment: If the problem is that a *different* random string is appended each time you hit Publish, I suggest you modify the filter to add a postmeta 'slug-modified' or something like that, and modify the filter so that it only adds a random string when this postmeta doesn't exist.

Comment: this is hard to answer without seeing your code

Comment: @MarkKaplun, I have edited my original post.